# pandas output to CSV - how to save date in title row?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to script a data extract daily.

I need the script to output into a csv like this,

[image]

At the moment I have a dataframe like this that I am saving to csv format.

[image]

Additionally, one of the columns has integers that are sometimes represented like, 001. When outputted to the CSV, the 00 is automatically removed - I need it to remain as well.

#### using code below, still not able to keep the 0 integers in the CSV : /

Would appreciate some guidance on solving this issue - Thank you!

Comment: What is `001` ? It is value of column name, e.g. instead `Fruit` ? Or instead `Apples` ?

Comment: It's a value of fruit number, so e.g, Banana - 001 - 1337.69

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `DataFrame` with `date` value, write to file and then write `df` with `mode='a'` for appending:

```
#'08/09/2020'
date = pd.Timestamp('now').strftime('%d/%m/%Y') 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit':[1], 'Fruit num':[1313]})
```

For convert integer to string use [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) with [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df['Fruit'] = df['Fruit'].astype(str).str.zfill(3)
print (df)
  Fruit  Fruit num
0   001       1313
```

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=[date])
df1.to_csv('file.csv',index=False)
df.to_csv('file.csv',index=False, mode='a')
```

Comment: Thanks - to get todays date, would i just use now?

Comment: And for the 001 int, did you turn that to string? I find that CSV does not format that correctly still (using astype('str')

Comment: Yeah - still won't keep the numbers in CSV : /

Comment: @LeCoda - Do you open it by excel? Or by some text editor like notepad++ ? Because unfortunately Excel used to convert strings `001` to integers `1`.

Comment: Yeah excel - so perhaps the CSV itself is fine